# How to visualize simple network in R? With or without D3

Tags: r, d3.js, data-visualization, htmlwidgets, networkd3

I need to visualize the connections between developers in repo1 and repo2.

In particular, I need to show:

- How some (not all) devs are active in both repos.
- Some devs are more active than others (the number of 'comm' or commits should be reflected in the size of the nodes, in the two repos.
- Repos are distinguished by color.

I've used [networkd3](/questions/tagged/networkd3) to create a simple network, but I struggle with the next steps.

```
library(networkD3)

df <- data.frame(devs = c("jeff", "jeff", "james", "james",
"mary", "alfred", "maggie"),repos=c("repo1", "repo2", "repo1", "repo2",
"repo1", "repo2", "repo1"), comm=c("3","3","6","6","3","3","3"))

simpleNetwork(df)
```

Desired output:

[image: Example]

I am new to network graphs, so if this isn't doable with [networkd3](/questions/tagged/networkd3) I'm open to suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restructure your data and use `networkD3::forceNetwork()`...

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

links <-
  df %>% 
  mutate(node = paste0(devs, "_", repos)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(devs, comm), names_from = repos, values_from = node) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(repo1) & !is.na(repo2)) %>% 
  mutate(value = 1L) %>% 
  select(source = repo1, target = repo2, value)

nodes <-
  df %>% 
  mutate(id = paste0(devs, "_", repos)) %>% 
  mutate(node_size = as.numeric(comm) * 30) %>% 
  select(id, name = devs, group = repos, node_size)

links$source_id <- match(links$source, nodes$id) - 1L
links$target_id <- match(links$target, nodes$id) - 1L

forceNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes, Source = "source_id", 
             Target = "target_id", Value = "value", NodeID = "id", 
             Nodesize = "node_size", Group = "group", opacity = 1L, 
             opacityNoHover = 1L, fontSize = 14L)
```

[image]

links

```r
#> # A tibble: 2 × 5
#>   source      target      value source_id target_id
#>   <chr>       <chr>       <int>     <int>     <int>
#> 1 jeff_repo1  jeff_repo2      1         0         1
#> 2 james_repo1 james_repo2     1         2         3
```

`source_id` and `target_id` are the 0-indexed row/index of the node in the `nodes` data frame

`value` should be 1 unless you want to define different values for the weight of the link

nodes

```r
#> # A tibble: 7 × 4
#>   id           name   group node_size
#>   <chr>        <chr>  <chr>     <dbl>
#> 1 jeff_repo1   jeff   repo1        90
#> 2 jeff_repo2   jeff   repo2        90
#> 3 james_repo1  james  repo1       180
#> 4 james_repo2  james  repo2       180
#> 5 mary_repo1   mary   repo1        90
#> 6 alfred_repo2 alfred repo2        90
#> 7 maggie_repo1 maggie repo1        90
```

`id` or `name` is the name of the node that will be displayed in the plot (there can be more than one node with the same name if you want)

`group` is the group the node is in (these are arbitrary group names and they can all be the same or not)

`node_size` gives the size of the node in the plot

The column names in your `links` and `nodes` data frames need to be explicitly specified in the `forceNetwork()` function call e.g.

`Source = "source_id"`
`Target = "target_id"`
`Value = "value"`
`NodeID = "id"`
`Nodesize = "node_size"`
`Group = "group"`

Comment: This looks great, is there a way to cluster the two repos, for instance with repo1 on the left side and repo2 on the right side?

Comment: No, not with {networkD3}. It is designed to automatically, algorithmically determine the layout, and facilitate interaction.... less so for manually choosing the layout.

Comment: I mean, is there a way to cluster the network by the "repos" variable in the original df?

Comment: The data is there in the original df, but it is not in the format required by `forceNetwork()`. `simpleNetwork()` does not do grouped coloring.

Comment: Ah I see. Can you help me understand how the data should be re-structured?

Comment: edited answer for more explanation about the format of the `links` and `nodes` data frames